# How to use a wired headphone AND a mic at the same time on the Macbook Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones, microphone

I'm surprised that the Macbook Pro Retina has only one 3.5mm audio jack. It seems that port can be either headphone or mic in depending on what's connected but I need BOTH at the same time for Skype! My Skype headset has 2x 3.5mm jacks - one for output (headphones) and one for input (Mic).

How is Apple expecting us to use Skype on the MPBr? I've tried:

- in-built speakers + in-build mic: The loudspeaker throws feedback into the built-in mic => unusable
- headphones + in-built mic: Keyboard clicks and other ambient noises are picked up => unusable
- microphone + speakers: Works but I can't use this unless I close my office door (i.e. only person in the room). I can't use this in coffee shops, campus areas, shared office environments etc
- Bluetooth headset: Its a pain to make sure the headset is fully charged before the call and that it doesn't kill my WiFi (which it sometimes does).

How can I get a real wired headphone and mic to work with the MBPr? This thing is killing my conference calls ...

Comment: I use a USB headset with mic.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem only it is for the conference room in work so I need to have a mic and a speaker attached so that multiple listeners can hear. this rules out a headsets - please help!

Comment: @Treasa: Try Jason's comment above or search for "3.5mm male TRRS splitter" (http://lmgtfy.com/?q=3.5mm+TRRS+male+splitter) Example of product: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-MUYHSMFF-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B004SP0WAQ/ref=pd_bxgy_e_img_z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need the same type of headset that you use with an iPhone. It will have one 3.5mm plug that carries both the stereo audio and mic input (aka a TRRS plug). Some examples are apple's own [EarPods](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD827LL/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic), Sennheiser's PX 200-II i's, and any other iPhone headset.

Comment: Confirmed that this works when I use my iPhone5's earpods on the MBPr...

Comment: Using this with a Retinabook: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004SP0WAQ/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1