# 3.5mm mic: how to explain my MacBook that it's just a mic and not an headphone set

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

Like title, I'm using a [Boya M1](https://www.amazon.it/microfono-lavalier-smartphone-Canon-fotocamera/dp/B00MPDYGBE/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=boya&qid=1590471014&sr=8-3) lavalier mic with a 3.5 mm plug. When I put it into the jack (that is the same of the headphones), my audio go mute, because computer thinks I'm using a headphone.
Luckily, the mic works as expected, but I can not hear any audio. So if I am in a conference, I cannot hear them.

Is there is a software solution? If not, what hardware solution could I use?

Comment: Check your sound system prefereces and set ouput to internal speakers.

Comment: Hehehe. That's the real problem, when I put mic's jack in it only show me the "headphone" as audio output. :(

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify this. It's most likely a hardware issue though.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a microphone jack. You plugged your microphone in the headphone jack. This is why you can not select internal speakers.

Try one of these adaptors:

USB Type A:

https://www.amazon.com/customerpicks/Explore-usb-adapters-for-microphone/49a722acca2e7546619b

USB Type C:

[https://www.amazon.com/CableCreation-External-Headphone-Microphone-Compatible/dp/B075YFDJ4Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075YFDJ4Q)

[https://www.amazon.com/Headphone-Microphone-Plantronics-Sennheiser-Compatible/dp/B07KPLDJ18](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KPLDJ18)

Or get a USB microphone and skip the adaptor.

https://www.amazon.com/usb-microphone/s?k=usb+microphone

https://www.amazon.com/usb-c-microphone/s?k=usb-c+microphone

### Perhaps the jack is for a headset (combination microphone/headphone).

There is this question: [How to use a wired headphone AND a mic at the same time on the Macbook Pro Retina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67098/how-to-use-a-wired-headphone-and-a-mic-at-the-same-time-on-the-macbook-pro-retin?rq=1). The answer would suggest the jack would accept a plug with two rings. This would allow the jack to be used for a mono microphone and stereo headphones. If this is your arrangement, then the you still would need a USB solution since using the jack would not allow the internal speakers to be used.

[image]

Although, you have to wonder. If you used the microphone jack and left the headphone jack unused of an adaptor, like [the one shown below](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004SP0WAQ), then could the internal speakers be accessed? My guess is probably not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

- [a simple headset splitter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC9Yb.png)  You can pick these up pretty much any store that sells cell phone and computer accessories
- [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271).  This gives you a digital audio input/output device connected to USB.

The port on your Mac is a combo headphone and microphone.  When you plug in a device, it *physically* trips a switch that turns off your internal microphone and speakers.  This is why you can no longer see the internal microphone or speakers are input/output sources.

I personally prefer the USB DAC because it's totally separate and you can now use a combination of input and output devices.  For instance you can use the
Boya M1 and the internal speakers.  You can use the internal Mic and external speakers.  I use my DAC for sending quality audio to my Bose while system sounds remain on the internal speakers.

Comment: DAC means digital to analog. A microphone would require a analog to digital converter. Do you know for a fact that an adaptor plugged into the 3.5 mm jack would allow the internal speakers to be used?

Comment: The DAC that I linked to and personally use does in fact have both analog input and output.  Did you check it? Because the question is literally about accepting *analog* input to USB.